# Как удаленно перегрузить свич compex ps2208b?

Tags: свич

На работе в одном из кабинетов стоит такой свич. Очень редко, но тем не менее бывает, что он виснет что ли. Решение кардинальное - выдернуть из розетки и снова включить. Но мне кажется, было бы намного проще, если бы я с удаленного компа его перегружал просто. Как это можно сделать? Айпишника его я не знаю, если вообще есть на нём. Если есть - как узнать. Если нет - как перегрузить? Если вообще есть такая возможность в принципе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приобретите какое-нибудь из устройств [NetPing](http://www.netping.ru).

Comment: То есть просто запросом с компа никак, да? Ну хотя это логично в какой-то мере, рез свич завис))

Comment: Тут даже дело не в логичности,потому что иногда бывает,что свич доступен,а работает не корректно,просто ваш сompex ps2208b неуправляемый.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.